# onSubmit show DIV at start of the php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have a simple form, like this:

```
<form id="uploadform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="file_up" name="Filedata[]" />
<input type="submit" id="send" name="uploadenFormSend" value="Bestand(en) uploaden" class="button-pink">        
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, a php script on the same page runs. (no JS or Jquery)
I like to do the following:

When the php script is started, a DIV with ID "progress" needs to be shown.
At the end op the php script, it has to hide the DIV.

Can i do this with JS or jQuery?

I tries the following:

At the top of the PHP script:

```
echo '<script>
        document.getElementById("uploadStatus").style.display = "";
    </script>';
```

At the end of the php script:

```
echo '<script>
        document.getElementById("uploadStatus").style.display = "none";
    </script>';
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work..
Can someone help me?

Comment: So you're trying to show a loader until the page loads?

Comment: Unless you have a lot of information to send to the user (I'm talking pages and pages of information), I would not do this. Just allow the page to load naturally and be done with it. With the way you are sending the HTML down to the client, you will never see this happen anyways. You would need to force send down partial information to the client for this to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#uploadStatus").hide()
});
```

Just make sure you have the ID visible by default.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to submit without reloading the page. In case I'm right, you could use Ajax. Here is a possible solution using jQuery (not tested yet) :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
        $('#uploadStatus').show();
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('action'), 
            $(this).serialize(),
            function () {
                $('#uploadStatus').hide();
            }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

The PHP script which retrieves the data must be in a separate file, example :

```
<form action="path/to/submit.php" ...
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing you need to keep in mind is that PHP is server side and javascript/JQuery is client side. All PHP code runs prior to ever reaching your browser. The javascript/JQuery all runs in your browser. When you use the submit button you are sending a request to the server for a new page.

With that said you have 2 options:

Just show your progress div on submit:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
    $('#uploadStatus').show();
  });
});
```

This will show the progress bar while waiting for the server to finish the request and return it for the new page load.

Or you can do an ajax request as @wared mentioned which may or may not be more than you want to get into.

Either way your progress div should have style="display:none" to start with.